# Is it possible to declare relationship after class is created by automap in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, relationship, automap

I'm new to sqlalchemy. I have followed the tutorial to create the automap of a existing db with relationship from a mysql db

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base, generate_relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from config import constr, mytables

def _gen_relationship(base, direction, return_fn,
                  attrname, local_cls, refferred_cls, **kw):
    return generate_relationship(base, direction, return_fn, attrname, local_cls, refferred_cls, **kw)

engine = create_engine(constr)
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=mytables)
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, generate_relationship=_gen_relationship)
Tableclass1 = Base.classes.table1
Tableclass2 = Base.classes.table2
```

`Table2.ID` maps to one of `table1`'s columns. But when I was trying to use query and join `table1` and `table2`, it reports error saying that "Can't find any foreign key relationships". Since I know the relationship of these 2 tables, is there way for me the declare this relationship after the class instance has been created? Or is there way to explicitly tell this relationship in query function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to do this in the query as @mpolednik mentioned, if I read your question correctly, the ideal solution would be to have the relationship declared in your classes for repeated use.

It can be achieved simply by pre-declaring the class that you wish to use, like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String

Base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/mydb")

# pre-declare User for the 'user' table
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    # override schema elements like Columns
    oname = Column('originalname', String)

    # and a relationship. I name it 'weird' because in my database schema
    # this relationship makes absolutely no sense, but it does demonstrate
    # the point
    weird = relationship("usergroup",
                         foreign_keys='usergroup.id',
                         primaryjoin='and_(usergroup.id==User.id)')

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
session = Session(engine)

# Test this by querying the User table and then following the relationship
u = session.query(User).filter(User.oname == 'testuser').one()
print (u.oname)
for g in u1.weird:
    print g.name
```

See here for the docs (including another example): http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html?highlight=automap#specifying-classes-explicitly

Answer (score 1):

You can do that explicitly by using `onclause` paremeter of join SQLAlchemy's `join` method. The `onclause` paremeter is used similary to SQL's JOIN e.g.

```
sqlalchemy.orm.join(table1, table2, onclause=table2.ID == table1.your_attribute)
```

You can also state bypass the existence of foreign key in database by simply stating the foreign key in the class:

```
Column('ID', Integer, ForeighKey('table1.your_attribute'))
```